# datastructure that holds closures, parametrically in scala

Tags: scala, types, closures, bounds, parametric-polymorphism

I am implementing a GUI event system in Scala. I have something like:

```
case class EventObject
case class KeyEventObject extends EventObject
case class MouseEventObject extends EventObject
```

I would like to store event listener closures in a (multi-)map, like so:

```
var eventListeners = new MultiMap[EventDescriptor, (EventObject => Unit)];
```

My question is, is there some way to rewrite this so that the function signatures of the stored closure can be EventObject or any subclass? Something like the following:

```
var eventListeners = new MultiMap[EventDescriptor, [A <: EventObject](A => Unit)]
```

so that I can have the subtype known when I define the listener functions:

```
eventListeners.put(KEY_EVENT, (e:KeyEventObject) => { ... })
eventListeners.put(MOUSE_EVENT, (e:MouseEventObject) => { ... })
```

Comment: I must say that some your code in deprecated, you should check this conversation: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-ide-dev/PyejSImLLtE/EbqqSKPUMisJ - and there find words, "Case-to-case inheritance is prohibited"...

Comment: I did not know that, I standardized on scala 2.9 but maybe it's time to upgrade.

Comment: @DaveRafkind: It's a good idea to avoid case-to-case inheritance in 2.9, too, where it's not prohibited but will result in compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that many things are impossible. You can do the following, for example, with type classes:

```
class HMultiMap {
  import scala.collection.mutable.{ Buffer, HashMap }

  type Mapping[K, V]

  private[this] val underlying = new HashMap[Any, Buffer[Any]]

  def apply[K, V](key: K)(implicit ev: Mapping[K, V]) =
    underlying.getOrElse(key, Buffer.empty).toList.asInstanceOf[List[V]]

  def add[K, V](key: K)(v: V)(implicit ev: Mapping[K, V]) = {
    underlying.getOrElseUpdate(key, Buffer.empty) += v
    this
  }
}
```

And now:

```
sealed trait EventObject
case class KeyEventObject(c: Char) extends EventObject
case class MouseEventObject(x: Int, y: Int) extends EventObject

sealed trait EventDescriptor
case object KEY_EVENT extends EventDescriptor
case object MOUSE_EVENT extends EventDescriptor

class EventMap extends HMultiMap {
  class Mapping[K, V]

  object Mapping {
    implicit object k extends Mapping[KEY_EVENT.type, KeyEventObject => Unit]
    implicit object m extends Mapping[MOUSE_EVENT.type, MouseEventObject => Unit]
  }
}
```

It's a little messy, but the usage is much prettier:

```
val eventListeners = new EventMap

eventListeners.add(KEY_EVENT)((e: KeyEventObject) => println(e.c))
eventListeners.add(MOUSE_EVENT)((e: MouseEventObject) => println("X: " + e.x))
eventListeners.add(KEY_EVENT)((e: KeyEventObject) => println(e.c + " again"))
```

We can confirm that we can pick out individual kinds of event handlers:

```
scala> eventListeners(KEY_EVENT).size
res3: Int = 2
```

And we can pretend to fire an event and run all the handlers for it:

```
scala> eventListeners(KEY_EVENT).foreach(_(KeyEventObject('a')))
a
a again
```

And it's all perfectly safe, since nothing gets into the underlying loosely-typed map without the proper evidence. We'd get a compile-time error if we tried to add a function from `String` to `Unit`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible.

Let's suppose you have such `Map`:

```
val f = eventListeners(key).head
```

How would you call the function `f`? With parameter of type `EventObject`? You can't. It could be `KeyEventObject => Unit`. With parameter of type `KeyEventObject`? You can't. It could be `MouseEventObject => Unit`.

You can use `PartialFunction[EventObject, Unit]` and check for `isDefinedAt` every time, but it's an ugly way.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Seems impossible. Also a case-to-case inheritance gets prohibited in Scala-2.10

...

Maybe by using some specific trait and declaring event object classes sealed and extend that trait?

```
val eventListeners = new MultiMap[EventDescriptor, ((_ >: EventTrait) => Unit)]
```

From `List` sources:

```
:+[B >: A, That](elem: B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

`That` - is a specific type, it could be built from your EventTrait by implicit builder, one builder for each event type. Instead of `elem: B` try use classOf[B]. Create get methods that will access your `MultiMap` using different classOf:

```
def getMouseEvent(ed: EventDescriptor) = multimap.entrySet.filter(
(a, b) => a == ed ).map((a, b) => (a, convertTo(ClassOf[MouseEvent], b)).
filter((a, b) => b != null)
```

`convertTo` returns null if it could not convert event to appropriate type

Ugly.

Comment: val a: List[((_ >: Option[_]) => Unit)] = List((_: Int) => {}) - does not allow add function from Int

Comment: There's no  way to call functions from such collection. It's possible to add `Nothing => Unit`.

Comment: He will not add Nothing or AnyRef and all will be fine